# Can we express a divergenceless second order tensor as the curl of something?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, divergence-operator

From my electromagnetism courses I remember that a divergenceless vector field (such as the magnetic field) can be expressed as the curl of another vector field:

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{0} \Leftrightarrow \boldsymbol{b} =  \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{a}$$

I am wandering if a similar expression exists for second order tensors. More precisely, if I consider a 2D symmetric second-order tensor such as:

$$ \boldsymbol{T} = \begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ c & b \end{bmatrix}$$

and assume that it verifies

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{T} = \boldsymbol{0}$$

Can I express it as an algebraic combination of the nabla operator and some other vector and/or tensor fields?

Comment: The keyword is York decomposition. Such questions have been analyzed quite extensively in the context of general relativity. For example, see https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9606055 or http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPA_1967__7_2_149_0. These papers address this question in a more general setting.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll look into it !